# In a proof by induction, can one prove the inductive step by contradiction?

Tags: induction

Proof by induction consists in following scheme:

[Proof by induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction)

or intuitively, let be a predicate $ P(n) $ with $ n \in \Bbb{N} $:

if

1. $P(0) $ is true
2. $P(k)\to P(k+1), \forall k \in \Bbb{N} $ is true

then $P(n), \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ is true

but can I proof by contradiction the point 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove however you want either point 1 or 2. As long as their proofs are valid, by the induction theorem you can conclude that $P$ holds for all natural numbers.